# Adjust the spacing between chapter & section or section & subsections or subsections and subsubsections with no prose between the header

Tags: spacing, titlesec

I am trying to adjust the spacing between `\chapter` & `\section`, `\section` & `\subsection`, and `\subsection` & `\subsubsection` that have no prose between the headers to get the same spacing between subheadings.  I need to have a triple space (`3ex`) above all headers and a double space (`2ex`) before all text. (These dimensions can also be `\baselineskip`s, they just need to be consistent)

In my class file I am using `titlesec` to have full control over headers.  However, I can't seem to get the spacing correct without adding a negative `\vspace`:

```
\titlespacing{\chapter}
             {0in}
             {1in}
             {3ex}
             [0in]

\titlespacing{\section}
             {0in}
             {3ex}
             {1ex}
             [0in]

\titlespacing{\subsection}
             {0in}
             {3ex}
             {1ex}
             [0in]

\titlespacing{\subsubsection}
             {0in}
             {3ex}
             {0in}
             [0in]

\titlespacing{\paragraph}
             {1em}
             {-0.5\baselineskip}
             {1ex}
             [0in]

\titlespacing{\subparagraph}
             {1em}
             {-0.5\baselineskip}
             {1ex}
             [0in]

\titleformat{\chapter}  % command
    [display]           % shape (Creates new line after the word "CHAPTER ii"
    {\color{red}\centering\normalfont\Large\bfseries\doublespacing} % format
    {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \vspace{3ex} \Large\thechapter} % label
    {0in}               % separations (horizontal)
    {\MakeUppercase}    % before
    [\vspace{3ex}]                  % After (leave blank)

\titleformat{\section}  % command
    [hang]           % shape %
    {\centering\singlespacing\normalfont\Large\bfseries} % format
    {\thesection} % label
    {1ex}               % separations (horizontal)
    {}                  % before
    [\vspace{1ex}]                  % After (leave blank)

\titleformat{\subsection}  % command
    [hang]              % shape
    {\centering\singlespacing\normalfont\large\bfseries} % format
    {\thesubsection} % label
    {1ex}               % separations (horizontal)
    {}                  % before
    [\vspace{1ex}]                  % After (leave blank)

\titleformat{\subsubsection}  % command
    [hang]                 % shape
    {\centering\singlespacing\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries} % format
    {\thesubsubsection} % label
    {1ex}               % separations (horizontal)
    {}                  % before
    [\vspace{1ex}]                  % After (leave blank)

\titleformat{\paragraph}  % command
    [runin]                 % shape
    {\centering\singlespacing\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries} % format
    {\theparagraph} % label
    {1ex}               % separations (horizontal)
    {}                  % before
    [\hspace*{1ex}]                  % After (leave blank)

\titleformat{\subparagraph}  % command
    [runin]                 % shape
    {\centering\singlespacing\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries} % format
    {\thesubparagraph} % label
    {1ex}               % separations (horizontal)
    {}                  % before
    [\hspace*{1ex}]                  % After (leave blank)
```

What I am trying to avoid is this:

```
\chapter{\uppercase{Chapter 1}}
    
\vspace{-2ex} % Space between chapter and section with no text (Try to avoid this)

\section{Section 1}

\vspace{-1ex} % Space between section & subsection with no text (Try to avoid this)

\subsection{Subsection 1}
```

vs.

```
\chapter{\uppercase{Chapter 1}}
    
\lipsum[66]

\section{Section 1}

\lipsum[66]

\subsection{Subsection 1}
```

Would anyone have an idea where I can make this adjustment?

Answer (score 0):

I defined my title spacing like this (copied from somewhere and adjusted until I was satisfied), and in the result it does not matter whether there is text or a chapter title above a section title. But I do not want to mess up my thesis, so please try yourself whether you can change the plus and minus parameters. I have not found any explanation for how it works in the documentation.

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Large\bf}{\thechapter{.~}}{0pt}{\Large\bf\lineskiplimit=-\maxdimen}%
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\bf}{\thesection{.~}}{0pt}{\bf\lineskiplimit=-\maxdimen}%
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\bf}{\thesubsection{.~}}{0pt}{\bf\lineskiplimit=-\maxdimen}%
\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{1ex plus 3ex minus .2ex}{2ex plus .2ex}%minder ruimte boven en onder hoofdstuktitel
\titlespacing*{\section} {0pt}{3.5ex plus 3ex minus .2ex}{1ex plus .2ex}%minder ruimte boven en onder sectiontitel
\titlespacing*{\subsection} {0pt}{3.5ex plus 3ex minus .2ex}{1ex plus .2ex}%minder ruimte boven en onder sectiontitel
```